# jquery passing serialize form in $.post()

Tags: jquery

I have this function and it executes upon submitting a form. How can i serialize the whole form and pass it?

```
function addToCart(el)
{
    console.log(el.action);



    $.post(el.action, { id: 'df'}, 
        function(returnedData){
             console.log(returnedData);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  var api = 'http://localhost/api';
  $( "form" ).on( "submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var payload = $( this ).serializeArray();

    $.post(api, payload, function(response) {
      console.log("response", response);
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks it workks perfectly. one question, is it better than having to use $.ajax()?